# Represent a prime number as a sum of four squared integers

Tags: algorithm, number-theory

Given a prime number p, find a four integers such that p is equal to sum of square of those integers.

1 < p < 10^12.

If p is of form 8n + 1 or 8n + 5, then p can be written as sum of two squares. This can be solved in O(sqrt(p)*log(sqrt(p)). But for other cases,i.e. when p cannot be written as sum of two squares, than is very inefficient. So, it would be great if anyone can give some resource material which i can read to solve the problem.

Comment: Show us what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: I don't see the point of downvotes or close votes. OP already mentioned what he tried, which was a good try. And the question is perfectly find for SO.

Comment: *give some resource material which I can read to solve the problem.* is technically off-topic for SO. That being said, there's a paper on how to represent any positive integer `n` as the sum of four squares (I think it's not free though):
http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cpa.3160390713/abstract;jsessionid=F4064FCACA7BF0A841CF6D8EAD3C340B.f02t01
And here an explanation of the algorithm for three squares:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483101/rabin-and-shallit-algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Given your constraints, I think that you can do a smart brute force.

First, note that if p = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2, each of a, b, c, d have to be less than 10^6. So just loop over a from 0 to sqrt(p). Consider q = p - a^2. It is easy to check whether q can be written as the sum of three squares using [Legendre's three-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem). Once you find a value of q that works, a is fixed and you can just worry about q.

Deal with q the same way. Loop over b from 0 to sqrt(q), and consider r = q - b^2. [Fermat's two-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares) tells you how to check whether r can be written as the sum of two squares. Though this check requires O(sqrt(r)) time again, in practice you should be able to quickly find a value of b that works.

After this, it should be straightforward to find a (c,d) pair that works for r.

Since the loops for finding a and b and (c,d) are not nested but come one after the other, the complexity should be low enough to work in your problem.

Comment: Thanks ..But if the process has to be repeated for different prime numbers, than shouldn't this be inefficient.

Comment: Then yes of course. But I don't think the practical runtime would be much worse than the 8n+1 / 8n +5 case that you talked about in the question. How many prime numbers will you have to split like this approximately?